# running java ".class" in PHP

Tags: java, php, wampserver

Hi I'm new to programming in PHP. I use a WAMP server -> Apache version 2.4.4 and PHP version 5.4.16

I want to execute java program from php script, here's my java program

```
   file : test.java
    import java.io.*; 
    public class test {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
```

I used

```
exec("javac test.java");
exec(java test);
```

and it's no use. So then I tried to put the command code in "runfile.bat"

```
javac test.java > error.txt
java test > output.txt
```

when I execute runfile.bat by left clicking twice, it run perfectly and there's text "Hello World" in output.txt

then I try from PHP:

```
exec('start /B /C runfile.bat');
```

... and output.txt has nothing in it.

Comment: What folder do you run your program in? It looks like you place runfile.bat in the same folder. When you double click it, Windows automatically starts the file in the appropriate folder. When you execute the bat through `exec` or Task Scheduler you should add the working directory.

Comment: i placed the runfile.bat in the same folder as php

Comment: this is my full code 
`$curdir = getcwd(); 
   chdir('./Programs');
   echo getcwd();
   $result=shell_exec('cmd.exe /b /c runfile.bat');
   echo $result;
   chdir($curdir);`

Comment: Do you mind voting up my comment because it's the same as the answer below :)

Comment: Seems you are new to StackOverflow. Please accept the correct answer

Comment: sorry my reputation still 5 (i'm new to stackoverflow)

Comment: [UPDATE] i tried again and got the correct answer one, thx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to fully-qualify paths here (*especially* if this is a web application):

```
exec("javac test.java");
exec("java test");
```

Something more like:

```
exec("/path/to/javac /and/the/path/to/test.java");
exec("/path/to/java /and/the/path/to/test");
```

It's possible that it's "running" but the working directory isn't correct, so maybe it can't find the `javac` and `java` executables or *can* find them but can't find `test.java`.  When you run these things manually the executables are in your path and the file is in your working directory, but both of those may not be true for the PHP context.

Aside from that, it's also good practice to fully-qualify things anyway.  It's more explicit and less prone to error (or even exploit, if a user were to somehow upload a `javac` executable of their own to your website they could execute it with elevated permissions using your script).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely PHP's exec() would do.

```
<?php
exec('java test', $output, $return_var);

// `$output` captures the output of command executed
print_r($output);

// Generally `$return_var` becomes 0 if the command was successful
if (0 == $return_var) {
    // Command successfull
}
?>
```

PS: 
Make sure your Java class-paths are correct.
Always look for [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) -- which the best ever manual I've ever seen.